# DCGANを行う際に「'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable」というエラーが発生

Tags: python, tensorflow, numpy

DCGANで画像の自動生成を行う際に「'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable」というエラーが発生します。コードは下のものです。GoogleColaboratoryで実行しています。

```py
# 本物データをGeneratorで生成したデータのスケールを-1~1で揃える

def scale(x, feature_ranges=(-1, 1)):
    # 0~1に変換
    x = ((x - x.min()) / (255 - x.min()))

    # -1~1に変換
    min, max = feature_ranges
    x = x * (max - min) + min
    return x

class Dataset:
    # val_fracでテストデータを学習中と学習後用に分離する
    # スケール関数は上のものを使うためscale_func=None
    def __init__(self, shuffle= False, scale_func=None):
        self.test_x, self.valid_x = test_img2, valid_img2
        self.test_y, self.valid_y = test_index, valid_index
        self.train_x, self.train_y = train_img2, train_index

        if scale_func is None:
            self.scaler = scale
        else:
            self.scaler = scale_func
        self.shuffle = shuffle

    # ミニバッチ生成の定義
    def batches(self, batch_size):
        if (self.shuffle).any():
            idx = np.arange(len(dataset.train_x))
            np.random.shuffle(idx)
            self.train_x = self.train_x[idx]
            self.train_y = self.train_y[idx]

        n_batches = len(self.train_y) // batch_size
        for ii in range(0, len(self.train_y), batch_size):
            x = self.train_x[ii:ii+batch_size]
            y = self.train_y[ii:ii+batch_size]

            yield self.scaler(x), y

　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　（中略）

# トレーニングの実行

dataset = Dataset(train_img2, test_img2)

losses, samples = train(net, dataset, epochs, batch_size, figsize=(10, 5))
```

これを実行すると次のようなエラーが出ます。

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-79c936bb63bd> in <module>()
      2 dataset = Dataset(train_img2, test_img2)
      3 
----> 4 losses, samples = train(net, dataset, epochs, batch_size, figsize=(10, 5))

1 frames
<ipython-input-14-07c181927757> in train(net, dataset, epochs, batch_size, print_every, show_every, figsize)
     14         for e in range(epochs):
     15             # バッチで取り出してパラメータの更新を行う
---> 16             for x, y in dataset.batches(batch_size):
     17                 # for文のたびにstep数を1増加
     18                 steps += 1

<ipython-input-6-f57b4d686916> in batches(self, batch_size)
     26             y = self.train_y[ii:ii+batch_size]
     27 
---> 28             yield self.scaler(x), y

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

定義した`self.scaler`を使ってxとyを返したいのですが，このようなエラーが出ます。
どのように修正すればこのエラーを解決できるのでしょうか？

Comment: Dataset クラスのコンストラクタが `def __init__(self, shuffle=False, scale_func=None)` となっていて、`dataset = Dataset(train_img2, test_img2)` としていますので、`scale_func` に `test_img2` がセットされています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、ipythonで以下の検証コードを実行します。

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: scaler = np.array([1])

In [3]: scaler(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-69fda89d0c8a> in <module>
----> 1 scaler(1)

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

これは、scalerが関数ではなく、`numpy.ndarray` オブジェクトであることを意味しています。このオブジェクトは関数のように呼び出すことはできません。つまり、scalerはデータであり、関数ではないことを意味しています。

`Dataset`のコンストラクタは、一番目の引数に`shuffle`, 二番目の引数に`scale_func`を定義しています。`scale_func`が指定されている場合、`self.scaler`に`scale_func`が代入されるようになっています。

この`scale_func`として指定されているのは`test_img2`です。

> ---> 28             yield self.scaler(x), y
>   TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

このエラーから推測すれば、`self.scaler`に代入された`test_img2`が`numpy.ndarray`である可能性が高いです。

対処方法として、`Dataset`クラスのインスタンス化の方法を確認し、コンストラクタの引数としてデータを指定する部分を追加する必要があります。

```
class Dataset:
    def __init__(self, train_img2, valid_img2, valid_img2, train_index, valid_index, test_index, shuffle= False, scale_func=None):
        self.test_x, self.valid_x = test_img2, valid_img2
        self.test_y, self.valid_y = test_index, valid_index
        self.train_x, self.train_y = train_img2, train_index

        if scale_func is None:
            self.scaler = scale
        else:
            self.scaler = scale_func
        self.shuffle = shuffle
```

Datasetのコンストラクタを呼び出す部分でも、これらのデータすべてを渡すよう変更します。

```py
dataset = Dataset(train_img2, valid_img2, valid_img2, train_index, valid_index, test_index)
```